# Best practice: Encrypted email-addresses in a-elements and screen readers

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, screen-readers, wai-aria

According to the [The Accessibility Project](http://a11yproject.com) screen reads make use of JavaScript.

> A common misconception among web developers is that screen readers only read the non-JavaScript page. Due to this misconception, we sometimes assume it’s unnecessary to make JavaScript apps and other functionality accessible. This is categorically false.
>
> Source: [MYTH: Screen readers don’t use JavaScript](http://a11yproject.com/posts/myth-screen-readers-dont-use-javascript/)

The question for me is still, in which way?

I place emails similar to this using JavaScript. A small function decrypts the value and stores it in the `href`-attribute as well as it replaces the placeholder text:

```
<a data-value="[encrypted email]">This E-Mail is being protected against bots. […]</a>
```

Which becomes something like this on document ready:

```
<a href="mailto:somebody@somedmaincom">somebody@somedmaincom</a>
```

My questions are:

- Is this way accessible?
- Do I have to apply an aria-role in addition to make clear, that the content is replaced with the real values using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Is it accessible? It depends on your JavaScript function. It would be easier to look at a page where this was implemented.

A few comments:

In general, as far as a screen reader is concerned, a link is a link and the screen reader will just read the link text ("This email is being protected... ") and the fact that it's a link. It's up to the browser to do something when the link is activated (but see comments below).

Your sample code doesn't have the href attribute. This usually means that the "link" (it's not treated as a link without href) cannot be reached with a keyboard, which would be an accessibility problem. Fix this by adding href (with any value), e.g. add href="#".

How do you trigger your script? A screen reader user will use a keyboard, so you'll get an enter key press to activate the link. Do you watch for mouse click events? Links (<a href...>) are a special case, pressing enter on a link will trigger the onclick event, so you should be OK here when following the link.

You mention placeholder text: this is a link and not an input field, so I assume you change the link text? How do you do this? If it happens on mouse hover then it would not be triggered for keyboard users (including screen reader). Add e.g. an onfocus event that triggers the same function when the keyboard focus reaches that field.

When you change the link text using JavaScript then the screensaver should "see" the change and read the new text (if it still reads the old text try a different method to change the link text, there are several ways to do this in JavaScript). I'm not sure though if the screensaver will read the new text immediately or if you need to move the screen reader focus back onto the text again yourself. You can force the screensaver to read the new text (no matter where the focus is) by adding the attribute role="alert" to the container element that contains the text.

If you have any other mouse events you also need to add corresponding keyboard events. But I think this is everything. Post a link to an example page then I can comment further.

Comment: I've updated the question to make the conversion a bit clearer. The placeholder text (I mean the text within the `a`-element before the conversion ;) ) gets replaced and a `href`-attribute is added of course. This happens on document ready. So will the screen reader see the updated link in any case and are all JavaScript functions executed like when accessing the page without a screen reader? Does a screen reader allow text changes through JavaScript? Thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It will probably work but does depend on your scripts. Is there a sample page/demo page I can test with a screen reader?